# Trigger Batch Job using rest webservice

Tags: java, spring, angular, spring-boot, spring-batch

My application is built on spring boot and angular 2. I am uploading a excel file from the angular 2 UI, which will be saved in server. I am planning to read this file and save it in DB using batch Job. I want to trigger the job using the rest webservice, Is this possible? My Aim is to trigger the job which reads the file and my services should not wait for the response. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all you gotta do is to schedule the saving of the file to the DB in a separate thread. You can use spring-batch or a plain old ExecutorService.
Your controller method would look something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public ResponseEntity<Void> upload(File file) {
    executorService.submit(new BatchFileDBUpload(file));
    return ResponseEntity.accepted().build();
}
```

Your `BatchFileDBUpload` class would need to be a `Runnable` or `Callable`

Comment: Will the service wait till the batch is complete or its just submit the batch job and return response entity.? My requirement is it should not wait for batch to complete. It's just has to trigger and return response.

Comment: It will return immediately after the job is scheduled but will not wait for the job to complete

Answer (score 0):

You can autowire JobLauncher and Job in your controller and trigger them manually:

```
@Autowired
JobLauncher jobLauncher;
@Autowired
Job job;

@RequestMapping("...")
public void runJob(){
    jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
}
```